Mongodb findone extremely slow even though the collection im searching is empty
I am having a simple login and it takes 3-4 seconds checking if a email is already used even though the user collection is completely empty and I have indexing applied.
Heres my code in rust:
#[post("/register")]
async fn register_post(form: actix_web::web::Form<LoginForm>, state: web::Data<AppState>) -> impl Responder {
    if EmailAddress::is_valid(&form.email, None) {

        let random_verification_code: i32 = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(100000..1000000);

        println!("{}", random_verification_code);

        tokio::spawn(utils::email::sendregisteremail(form.email.clone(), random_verification_code));

        let users:Collection<mongodb::bson::Document> = state.db.database("onecloud").collection("users");
        
        // Fast indexed lookup
        let filter = doc! { "email": &form.email };

        println!("t1");
        match users.find_one(filter, None).await {
        Ok(Some(_)) => {
            println!("User already exists");
        }
        Ok(None) => {
            println!("User does not exist");
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Database error: {}", e);
        }
    }

        let doc = mongodb::bson::doc! {
            "email": form.email.to_string(),
            "password": form.password.to_string(),
            "verification_code": random_verification_code
        };
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            match users.insert_one(doc, None).await {
                Ok(_) => {}
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("Error inserting document: {}", e);
                }
            }
        });
        HttpResponse::Ok()
            .content_type("text/html")
            .body(include_str!("../public/confirmcode.html"))
    } else {
        HttpResponse::Ok()
            .content_type("text/html")
            .body(include_str!("../public/error.html"))
    }
    


    /*let users = app_state.db.collection("users");
    let doc = mongodb::bson::doc! {
        "email": "tom@web.de"
    };
    users.insert_one(doc, None).await.unwrap();
  */
}


How are you timing this? I don't see any metrics within your code and your endpoint does much more than just find_one. Please provide a [mre]. Are you measuring the timing in a --release build?

It takes extreamly long inbetween the 't1' and the notification if the user exists

How do you know  the database search query findOne method is causing the slow performance? Have you tried the database query directly  from a database access tool like Compass or MongoDB shell and verified the slowness?
